# How can I keep my classes from being removed from mmenu Plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, sliding, mmenu

I am currently working with the mmenu jquery plugin. http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/documentation/core/off-canvas.html

Is there way to keep my class names that use in my navigation items when the mmenu plugin is triggered? They are removed and i have headings for menu items that I need to style.

**For reference:**

```html
<ul>
   <li><a class="dropdown-item nav-heading" href="#">Coffee Services</a></li>
   <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Quality Equipment</a></li>
   <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Our Coffees</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Becomes:**

```html
<ul class="mm-listview">
  <li class="mm-listitem"><a href="#">Coffee Services</a></li>
  <li class="mm-listitem"><a href="#">Quality Equipment</a></li>
  <li class="mm-listitem"><a href="#">Our Coffees</a></li>
</ul>
```

I need to keep the 'nav-heading' class!

Answer (score 1):

By some testing I discovered that the plugin removes all classes that are attached to any `div`, `a`, `li` or `span`. If you add classes to any other element inside the li tag, it does get copied over. So you can use an `i` element if you want the classes to be copied. For example:

```
<li>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
        <i class="nav-heading">
            Coffee Services
        </i>
    </a>
</li>
```

This will get copied like this:

```
<li class="mm-listitem">
    <a href="#" class="mm-listitem__text">
        <i class="nav-heading">
            Coffee Services
        </i>
    </a>
</li>
```

Then in your CSS counter the styling the `i` tag adds, and add your own:

```
.nav-heading {
    font-style: initial;

    // Add your styling
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what situation that you are facing. But if I found this trouble, I will use **Mutation Observer** for detecting changes of HTML element. You can insert 'nav-heading' into class attribute when you've detected any change of the element (The class attributes change).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Answer (score 0):

If your classes are removed by the plugin itself, nothing to do with that but you can dynamically add your desired class. Using this snippet may help you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.mm-listitem:eq(0)').addClass('nav-heading');
    $('.mm-listitem').on('click', function(){
        $('.mm-listview > *').removeClass('nav-heading');
        $(this).addClass('nav-heading');
    })
});
```